# Store a list of triplet with constant look up

Tags: java, algorithm, hash, hashmap, triplet

I would like to store a list of triplets of Enums- say `List<<Enum1, Enum2, Enum3>>` where I should be able to look up by any of the fields. What I mean is, say I store something like,

```
List<<Enum1, Enum2, Enum3>> list; 
list[0] = [ObjectOfEnum1, ObjectOfEnum2, ObjectOfEnum3]
list[1] = [ObjectOfEnum4, ObjectOfEnum5, ObjectOfEnum6]
list[2] = [ObjectOfEnum7, ObjectOfEnum8, ObjectOfEnum9]
list[3] = [ObjectOfEnum10, ObjectOfEnum11, ObjectOfEnum12]
.
.
```

I should be able to look up either by `ObjectOfEnum5` to get `list[1]` or by `ObjectOfEnum1` to get `list[0]`. I would like to get them in O(1). I am working with Java 8. Please point me to any data structure that could help me do this.

I can only think of having three Maps(each having a key of the different types of Enums) with the value of a tuple of the other 2. But this solution looks ugly.  Please let me know if there is something I can use.

Comment: Does the `ObjectofEnum` has any field that specifies its "index" like does `ObjectofEnum5` has any field that says it is 5th one?

Comment: @SomeDude They are enums and they correspond to numbers. They are not classes. Also `ObjectofEnum5` is just a random name, 5 does not mean anything, its just a name.

Comment: While you are storing the enums in a list as triplets, for each enum you could build a map of `Enum -> Index of List` and use that map later.

Comment: In Java, `enum` types *are* classes. So if your enums are something different, you should make clear what it is.